# Shader program compiles fine on Ati, fails on other vendors

Tags: opengl, shaders, glsl

Got a real annoying problem here.

My shader program compiles fine on my Ati Radeon HD card, but on Nvidia and Intel it failes to compile.

Vertex shader:

```
#version 120
attribute vec3 in_position;
 attribute vec3 in_normal;
 attribute vec3 in_texcoord;

 uniform mat4 modelMatrix;
uniform mat4 viewMatrix;
uniform mat4 projMatrix;

varying vec2 texture_coordinate;
varying vec3 normal;

void main()
{
gl_Position = (projMatrix * viewMatrix * modelMatrix) * vec4(in_position, 1.0);
normal = in_normal;
texture_coordinate = in_texcoord.xy;
}
```

Fragment shader:

```
#version 120
varying vec2 texture_coordinate;
varying vec3 normal;

uniform sampler2D gColorMap;

 void main()
 {
   gl_FragData[0] = vec4(texture(gColorMap, texture_coordinate).xyz, 1.0f);
   gl_FragData[1] = vec4(normalize(normal), 1.0f);
}
```

Any ideas? I checked the shader for errors, but I can't find anything. Thanks.

Comment: I haven't worked with OpenGL for some longer time. But I think attributes are available from version 130, aren't they?

Comment: Yup, that's it. Changed it to 130 and it now works fine :) Please add an answer so I can mark it.

Comment: What errors were you getting?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The GLSL function `texture` and the output `gl_FragData` are only available in GLSL version 1.30 or better.

So, change line `#version 120` to `#version 130`

To find compile problems you should use [glGetShaderInfoLog](http://www.opengl.org/sdk/docs/man/xhtml/glGetShaderInfoLog.xml) and [glGetProgramInfoLog](http://www.opengl.org/sdk/docs/man/xhtml/glGetProgramInfoLog.xml)

Comment: You're welcome. I'm glad I helped you :)